# SQL Code for Max and Min time based on condition ( IN / Out )

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access-2016

I have a table as below and I need to get another table query with

expected query return

```
date Username "Min(sign_time)based on IN" "Max(sign_time)based on out"
```

original table

```
Sign_Date   Employee_UserName   Sign    Sign_Time
27-Mar-19   abdullah.shaaban    In      8:14
27-Mar-19   abdullah.shaaban    Out     15:32
```

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MS Access?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is given that the IN timestamp is always smaller than the OUT timestamp for the same date/user combination, right? There is always an IN first, and always an out entry being the last one?

If so, you could use this one:

```
select 
   Sign_Date, 
   Employee_UserName, 
   Min(Sign_Time) as IN, 
   Max(Sign_Time) as Out
from Table
group by Sign_Date, Employee_UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are definitely using MS Access, you could use conditional aggregation with `iif` statements, e.g.:

```
select 
    t.sign_date, 
    t.employee_username, 
    min(iif(t.sign = 'In', t.sign_time, null)) as intime,
    max(iif(t.sign = 'Out', t.sign_time, null)) as outtime
from
    YourTable t
group by
    t.sign_date, 
    t.employee_username
```

An alternative solution is to use two correlated subqueries:

```
select
    t.sign_date,
    t.employee_username,
    (
        select min(u.sign_time)
        from YourTable u 
        where
            u.sign_date = t.sign_date and
            u.employee_username = t.employee_username and
            u.sign = 'In'
    ) as intime,
    (
        select max(u.sign_time) 
        from YourTable u 
        where 
            u.sign_date = t.sign_date and
            u.employee_username = t.employee_username and 
            u.sign = 'Out'
    ) as outtime
from
    YourTable t
group by
    t.sign_date, 
    t.employee_username
```

Or, you could use joins:

```
select 
    a.sign_date, 
    a.employee_username, 
    b.intime, 
    c.outtime
from
    (
        (
            select distinct t.sign_date, t.employee_username
            from YourTable t
        ) a
        left join
        (
            select t.sign_date, t.employee_username, min(t.sign_time) as intime
            from YourTable t
            where t.sign = 'In'
            group by t.sign_date, t.employee_username
        ) b
        on a.sign_date = b.sign_date and a.employee_username = b.employee_username
    )
    left join
    (
        select t.sign_date, t.employee_username, max(t.sign_time) as outtime
        from YourTable t
        where t.sign = 'Out'
        group by t.sign_date, t.employee_username
    ) c
    on a.sign_date = c.sign_date and a.employee_username = c.employee_username
```

In each of the above, change all occurrences of `YourTable` to the name of your table.

Syntax is for MS Access since both SQL Server and MS Access were tagged.